# Unable to select the data properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Helo,

I have written a query I want to show list of users to whom which current user is not following I am trying to do so but its showing me only 2 records and when I remove limit it shows me all users excluding the one that I have followed it is good but I do not know why it is showing only 2 users when I put limit to it as it should be 5 the first 3 users are not showing is it because I followed them here is my script I am unable to explain it properly But I would appreciate your comments so I can explain more accordingly

```
<?php
$sql = $this->db->limit(5);
$sql = $this->db->get('users');
foreach($sql->result() as $data):
$sql1 = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('user_id' => $data->id));
$sql2 = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('user_id' => $data->id, 'follower_id' => $user_id));
if($sql2->num_rows() != 0):
echo $data->username;
endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Table Structure followers

```
id(int)     
user_id(int)           
follower_id(int)
```

Table Structure users

```
id(int)     
username(varchar)           
email(varchar)
password(varchar)
```

Comment: can you post your table schema ?

Comment: @NavjotSingh users or followers ?

Comment: both tables users and followers

Comment: you want to fetch the user that is not followed by any user ?

Comment: that is not followed by logged in user.. so logged in user can follow that user

Comment: User this


<?php
$sql = $this->db->limit(5);
$sql = $this->db->get_where('followers',array('user_id'=>'current_user_id'));
foreach($sql->result() as $data):
$sql2 = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $data->id));
if($sql2->num_rows() != 0):
echo $data->username;
endif;
?

Comment: I did not found end of foreach like `endforeach;`... Please check for this also

Comment: @NavjotSingh it is not working for me bro I am getting 0 results because I noticed that you are checking if I have followed anyone if not then find that user id and what if no one had followed any users and i wanted to follow him first ?

Comment: @MarkAlan Use `$this->db->reset_query()` before start new query

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $this->db->start_cache();
    $sql = $this->db->limit(5);
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    $sql = $this->db->get('users');
    $this->db->flush_cache();

    foreach($sql->result() as $data):
    $this->db->start_cache();
    $sql1 = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('user_id' => $data->id));
    $this->db->flush_cache();

    $this->db->start_cache();
    $sql2 = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('user_id' => $data->id, 'follower_id' => $user_id));
    $this->db->flush_cache();

    if($sql2->num_rows() != 0):
    echo $data->username;
    endif;
    endforeach;
?>
```